# Phpmyadmin+codeigniter how can i auto update my data?

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

please help me i'm trying to make an auto update using phpmyadmin Trigger for my capstone title. is this correct?? i just need only to auto update in specific row only.

```
 SELECT * FROM event

     if((start_date==now())||end_date==now())
      THEN
      UPDATE event 
      SET 
           event_status = 'Ongoing'
         WHERE
        event_id = ????(Problem here);

         ELSEIF((start_date < now())&&(end_date>now()))
          THEN
           (some code)
          else if((start_date<now())&&(end_date<now()))
             (some code)
         ELSE
          (some code)
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have the pseudo rows NEW and OLD, as the name suggests it has all the columns with the old and new values

```
 if((start_date==now())||end_date==now())
  THEN
  UPDATE event 
  SET 
       event_status = 'Ongoing'
     WHERE
    event_id = NEW.event_id;

     ELSEIF((start_date < now())&&(end_date>now()))
      THEN
       (some code)
      else if((start_date<now())&&(end_date<now()))
         (some code)
     ELSE
      (some code)
```